# Como Guardar os Dados Para Gerar um PDF?

Tags: php, banco-de-dados, postgresql, pdf

Tem uma parte do sistema onde o usuário vai preencher uma série de informações apenas escolhendo entre opções de `selects`, esses `selects` são alimentados com informações que tenho cadastradas no meu banco de dados.

Quando eu for armazenar essas informações em sua devida tabela, é melhor que eu guarde diretamente o texto ou é melhor eu guardar o ID dos elementos que foram selecionados? E por que?

Essas informações serão utilizadas posteriormente para gerar um PDF que irá exibir todos os dados que foram guardados.

Acho que seria mais rápido na hora de gerar o PDF se eu armazenasse logo os textos, pois se eu armazenar o ID vou ter que fazer outras consultas para gerar o PDF certo? Mas isso seria errado de alguma forma? Vai gerar algum problema se optar por armazenar essa certa quantidade texto ao invés de armazenar somente o ID do elemento?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boa Raylan,

Isso depende, vai gerar muito trafego de rede? Pois requisitar ao servidor longas strings, ou muito "texto" pode sobrecarregar tua rede, não é interessante tu salvar os ids e gerar quando for requisitado?
  Outro detalhe, o banco de dados gerencia melhor indices e colunas do tipo longtext não é aceita em condições de Where ( ao menos no MySql ).
  Minha sugestão é salvar os ids e gerar tudo quando requisitado.

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Obrigado @PauloFlesch, vou ficar com a opção de armazenar os IDs msm.